# I am trying to email on edit, but it is not working due to the fail code listed in the body of this

Tags: email, google-sheets

This should be an easy one to fix and it'll probably be a duh moment, so here it is.  I have this google script written to send an email if a certain cell is a certain value.  It works just fine when "run".  I want it to run onEdit, but I get this notification when it fails:

TypeError: Cannot call method "getActiveSheet" of undefined. (line 3, file "Original Copy to make it send if b29 is less than 100")

Original Code:

```
    function email(e) 
    {
    var sheet = e.SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet1") {
    var activeCell = sheet.getRange("E1");
    if (activeCell.getA1Notation() == "E1") {
     if (activeCell.getValue() <100) 


     {
     MailApp.sendEmail("@gmail.com", "subject", "message")
    }
    }}}
```

Looking forward to that easy answer that I can't seem to find!  Thanks in Advance!

EPR

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the e.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

Comment: Took that e out.  Now I don't receive a failed message or an email from the sheet.  The script still runs just fine if you press run.

Comment: If you haven't created an on edit trigger then change the name of your function to onEdit instead of email

Comment: Such as this...function onEdit(e) 
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet1") {
    var activeCell = sheet.getRange("E1");
    if (activeCell.getA1Notation() == "E1") {
      if (activeCell.getValue() <100) 
        
        
{
  MailApp.sendEmail("@gmail.com", "freezer", "temp check for new script")
}
    }}}

Comment: neither onEdit(e) or onEdit() worked, but I was still able to manually run the code successfully.

Comment: now its working as emailonEdit(e) with and without the e.spreed area.  So confused.  Whatever, it works now I'll be back if it stops.  Thanks, utphx!

Comment: It looks like my answer of removing e. and creating a trigger solved your issue (those are the changes I see in your answer). The name of the function will not matter if you create an onEdit trigger. Let us know if the problem is solved. You can also accept your own answer which is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work the best.
I have a trigger set up using the google script trigger "button" to push this everytime the sheet edits.

function emailonEdit(e) 
    {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet1") {
    var activeCell = sheet.getRange("E1");
    if (activeCell.getA1Notation() == "E1") {
      if (activeCell.getValue() <100)

```
{
MailApp.sendEmail("@gmail.com", "freezer", "temp check for new script")
}
}}}
```